# C# developing tools on OS X

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, macos, ide

I was told that VisusalStudio has no version for Mac. So what should I use if I want to develop in C# on Mac ? Anybody has experiences with this ? I'm looking for native IDE, I don't want to run VS using VirtualBox or any virtualization solution.

And if I create application with WPF GUI will it run on Mac ? Or is WPF only for Windows GUI developing ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) is a free open source IDE based on the Mono project. There's builds available for Linux, MacOS X and Windows.

For GUI development, you'll need to use the GTK+ framework included with Mono - there's no plans to implement WPF on any platform other than Windows. GTK+ is cross-platform, though, so you can compile the same app for MacOS, Windows and Linux if you need to.

EDIT: It appears MonoDevelop also supports WinForms - http://www.mono-project.com/WinForms

There are a couple of alternative IDEs but nothing comparable to MonoDevelop in terms of features - but you can always just write C# code in your favourite editor and compile it using the Mono build tools, of course.

Comment: What about Windows forms ? Does it work for MaxOS X ? Are there any other IDEs then MonoDevelop ?

Comment: So my choice would be MonoDevelop and Silverlite or WindowsForms for GUI right ? So Silverlite or Windows Forms ? Article from your link says that Windows forms from Mono ships with win32 theme... That means that my GUI will look like windows GUI even if run on Mac ?

Answer (score 3):

WPF can run on any environment that supports it in its runtime environment. Currently that is only Windows since the Mono project has [no plans to implement WPF](http://www.mono-project.com/WPF)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Mono Project](http://mono-project.com/Main_Page).

For an IDE check out [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/).

You can also check out the [MonoTouch](http://monotouch.net/) to develop to the IPhone.

As already mentioned [WPF isn't supported](http://www.mono-project.com/WPF) but they do mention an alternative:

> Silverlight implement a subset of the
>   WPF APIs and is available on Windows,
>   MacOS X and through our own open
>   source effort Moonlight it is
>   available on Linux and other Unix
>   systems.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no complete IDE that support C# with intelli sense, etc.
So Vmware Fusion + Windows including Studio in Unity mode will be it :)

Simple C# syntax highlighting you can get with textmate.